# Divs in one column align, but immediately move another column down

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

My site has a 2 column layout that was working fine until I added 2 boxes that spanned 100% of the right column. (The About Me and Contact US boxes)  When I did that, the content in the left column was pushed to the bottom.

I kind of understand (I think) why it's happening.  I think my math is off somewhere and it's forcing the left column lower.  Either that or has something to do with block vs inline.

Here's what it looks like:

http://test.completesources.com/fitnesspro/

Everything on the right is perfect.  But that left sidebar content should be at the top of the page.

Here's my code:

http://jsbin.com/tucuha/edit?html,css,output

I really thought I could get this last bit myself, but I just don't have a starting point to shift the sidebar back.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your `.col2` inside `.colleft` as outside it will shift down due to the block-level element behaviour.

**Output:**
[image: Left sidebar]

[**JSbin**](http://jsbin.com/digosisiwa/1/edit?output)

Comment: beautiful!  Thanks.  That was much easier than I was making it.